# HTML en JtextPane JAVA

Tags: java, html, jframe

Tengo una pequeña duda, como imprimo una cadena dentro de un Panel de texto con etiquetas `html`?

Ejemplo:

```
jtextpane.setText("<html><body><font color=#16a085 size=6> Hola a todos! </font></body></html>");
```

@Dev. Joel Aca anexo el codigo

**JFrame 1**

```
private void impMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
linkedHashSet.addAll(arreglo);
        arreglo.clear();
        arreglo.addAll(linkedHashSet);


       String a="";

    for(int x=0; x<arreglo.size(); x++){

            a+=arreglo.get(x) +" " + arr.get(x)+"\n"; 

     }

        try {
            rs.impre(a);


        } catch (JessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test_v.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       imp.setVisible(false);}
```

**JFrame2**

```
 public void impre(String res) throws JessException {
    this.setVisible(true);
    jtimp.setContentType("text/html");
    jtimp.setText("<html><body><font color=#16a085 size=6><b>"
            + "A continuación se muestra el recorrido del árbol:<br> Síntomas: "
            + "Respuesta: <br></b></font>"+res+"</body></html>");


    }
```

Comment: @Dev. Joel Gracias por la respuesta, ahora el problema es que lo que imprimo en el panel de texto es una cadena... La cual viene de un metodo de otra clase, y en el metodo utilizo un for, dentro del for la cadena tiene saltos de lineas y tabulacion, en la impresion utilizando "text/html" en la otra clase, ya no me aparecen esos saltos de linea. como soluciono eso.?

Comment: ¿Saltos de línea y tab? es decir `\n` y `\t` ?  sí es así es obvio que no reconocerá. Recuerde que está imprimiendo `HTML` si desea saltos de línea quizá debería hacerlo con `<br>` y `TAB`  con `&#09;`

Comment: Si eso mismo pense, pero el problema es que son dos arreglos es decir **for(int x=0; x<arreglo.size(); x++){
    
            a+=arreglo.get(x) +"\t " + arr.get(x)+"\n"; 
            
     }** entonces al llevarlo a la clase donde se implementa el "text/html" llevo solo la cadena "a".

Comment: Actualice su pregunta. mi respuesta se baso en su duda principal. podría simplemente reemplazar  los valores de `\t` y `\n` con los que le mencione anteriormente. Recuerde que los comentarios no se pueden emplear para conversaciones extensas.

Comment: Listo, ya actualize, Disculpa soy Nuevo.

Comment: Excelente! Muchas Gracias @Dev. Joel. Bueno si habia tratado eso de cambiar los /n por <br> pero no sabia el de tabulacion. Solucionado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo está haciendo está bien , pero con una configuración adicional , es que debe asignar el tipo de contenido del `JTextPanel` haciendo uso de [setContentType("text/html")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType-java.lang.String-)

```
jtextpane.setContentType("text/html");
jtextpane.setText("<html><body><font color=#16a085 size=6> Hola a todos! </font></body></html>");
```

Las tabulaciones *(\t)* y los saltos de línea *(\n)* no se reconocen en `HTML` por lo tanto no le mostrará el formato que desea, el primer cambio sería reemplazar por elementos `HTML` tanto los saltos como las tabulaciones.

```
 String a="";

for(int x=0; x<arreglo.size(); x++){
   a+=arreglo.get(x) +" &#09; " + arr.get(x)+" <br>"; 
 }
```